# .bashrc not saving in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

In my `~/.bashrc` file, I have a function defined:

```
function today {
    echo "Today's date is:"
    date +"%A, %B %-d, %Y"
}
```

but every time I boot the machine, if I do

```
$ today
```

I get:

```
-bash: today: command not found
```

and then I have to `$ source .bashrc` (at every terminal) tab in order to activate this function and return:

```
Today's date is:
Thursday, November 2, 2017
```

Why is `.bashrc` "forgetting" its contents every time I reboot the machine?

### Edit

I have

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

declared in my `~/.profile`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash

Comment: Are you sure your shell is *bash* ? :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Your shell would be starting as an interactive login shell. In that case, bash read your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile, whichever it finds first. It does not automatically read the ~/.bashrc.

You should add this to your profile file:

```
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: I have this condition statement on my ~/.profile already. should I add this to ~/.bashrc as well?

Comment: Do you have a ~/.bash_profile file? Bash will use that first if both exist.

Comment: well, it works, but only if I move my ~/.profile contents into ~/.bash_profile. I don't see why it didi not work with ~/.profile

Comment: Maybe you have a ~/.bash_login. Read the documentation that I linked and check your dot-files.